# Displaying an array in a hashtable

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable with each element being an array:

```
PS\>$table

Name             Value
----             -----
Size             {2.72 GB, 5.18 GB}
Computer         {Server01, Server02}
Count            {363,765, 446,832}
```

Basically, I used the Invoke-Command to find the directory sizes of 2 computers rather than using a ForEach.  I would like to display the results like:

```
Computer       Count      Size
--------       -----      ----
Server01       363,765    2.72 GB
Server02       446,832    4.18 GB
```

Having difficulty trying to get the values split up to display.  I suspect I will have to use some sort of ForEach to create the display table.  But noit sure what to loop on.  TIA

```
$badmailtable | foreach {[PSCustomObject]$_}

Size               Computer             Count
----               --------             -----
{2.72 GB, 5.18 GB} {Server01, Server02} {363,765, 446,832}
```

[EDIT: Code below]
Original script:

```
$BadMailPath="D:\InetPub\mailroot\badmail"
$QueuePath="D:\InetPub\mailroot\queue"
$BadMailTable=@()
$QueueTable=@()
$Computers=@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Server="Server01";Alias="SV01.anydomain.com"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Server="Server02";Alias="SV02.anydomain.com"}
)
Foreach ($Svr in $Computers) {Write-Color "Retrieving ",$Svr.Server," contents     ",$Svr.Alias White,Yellow,White,Green}
$ScriptBlock = {param ($ParamPath) Get-ChildItem -path $ParamPath -recurse -force -erroraction silentlycontinue | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum,Count}
 
$Params = @{
    'Computer'=$Computers.Server
    'ScriptBlock'=$ScriptBlock
    'Credential'=$ADCred
    'ArgumentList'=$BadMailPath }
$BadMailFolderSize = Invoke-Command @Params

$Params = @{
    'Computer'=$Computers.Server
    'ScriptBlock'=$ScriptBlock
    'Credential'=$ADCred
    'ArgumentList'=$QueuePath }
$QueueFolderSize = Invoke-Command @Params
```

Comment: I think I know an easier/better way to go about this but you'll need to post the code you used to create the table.

Comment: Put the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own issue.  I added the following lines:

```
    Foreach ($record in ($BadMailFolderSize | sort-object -Property PSComputerName)) {
        $BadMailTable+= @{
            Computer = $record.PSComputerName
            Files = $record.Count
            Size = Format-FileSize $Record.sum
        }
    }
    Foreach ($record in ($QueueFolderSize | sort-object -Property PSComputerName)) {
        $QueueTable+= @{
            Computer = $record.PSComputerName
            Files = $record.Count
            Size = Format-FileSize $Record.sum
        }    
    }

Write-Host
Write-Color "D:\InetPub\mailroot\BadMail\" Yellow
$BadMailTable | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject]$_} | Format-Table Computer,@{n="Count";e={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Files};a="right"},@{n="Total Size";e={$_.Size};a="right"} -AutoSize
Write-Color "D:\InetPub\mailroot\Queue\" Yellow
$QueueTable | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject]$_}   | Format-Table Computer,@{n="Count";e={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Files};a="right"},@{n="Total Size";e={$_.Size};a="right"} -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, note that I'm hardcoding the Keys (in the inner `foreach` loop) because otherwise, if we use for example `$hash.Keys` you may end out not having the properties (columns) arranged the way you want them (first `Computer`, then `Count` and `Size` last).

```
$hash = @{
    Size     = '2.72 GB', '5.18 GB'
    Computer = 'Server01', 'Server02'
    Count    = '363,765', '446,832'
}

0..($hash['Computer'].Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {
    $out = [ordered]@{ }
    foreach($key in 'Computer', 'Count', 'Size') {
        $out[$key] = $hash[$key][$_]
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
}
```

If you have access to the code pulling this information from your hosts I would recommend you to update it from there so you wouldn't have a need to reconstruct these objects each time.